# How can we check PowerShell v2.0 is installed on a list of servers?

Tags: windows, powershell

How can I check if PowerShell v2.0 is installed on a list of servers? The list of servers is a combination of Windows Server 2003 and Windows Server 2008. A vbscript or PS script would be wonderful.

I know PowerShell is installed, by default, in Windows Server 2008, though I just like to make sure somebody was not messing with the servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging around and finding several places that lead to nothing usable in my environment, I was able  to find this.  This will work on systems that don't have Powershell, so it could be used for other registry scans.

```vb
$hostA = “RemoteComputer”
$cred = Get-Credential "domain\username"
$RegPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellEngine"
$ValueName = "PowerShellVersion"
$tmp = $(gwmi -computername $hostA -class win32_service -Credential $cred | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq “RemoteRegistry” })
if ( $($tmp.State) -eq "Stopped") {$tmp.StartService()}
$reg = Get-WmiObject -credential $Cred -List -Namespace root\default -computername $hosta | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "StdRegProv"}
$ref = ($reg.GetStringValue(2147483650,$RegPath,$ValueName)).sValue
if ($ref -eq $null ) {Write-Host $hostA "doesn't have Powershell"} else {Write-Host $hostA "has Powershell version" $ref}
```

Edit:  After looking around, it turns out this won't work if the Remote Registry service isn't running.  I added code to check for remote registry and start if stopped.  The `$cred = Get-Credential "domain\username"` can be removed along with `-Credential $cred` depending on your domain setup.

Edit2: Ok, I have found permission issues with using .OpenSubKey(). I am switching it to .GetValueKind(), since all we need to do is verify the key exist. Hopefully this works for you.  I don't have the permissions where I work to fully test this for you.

Edit3: I was having a lot of problems with permission in my environment since I cross untrusted domains.  I have rewrote the above code to work in my environment.  It works remotely, and doesn't require Powershell to be installed. Let me know if you get any other errors.

Comment: I tested on my PC first.
I replaced "RemoteComputer" with "FQDN of my server", and it tells me my PC does not have PowerShell.
I am not sure what the value of $ref is and how it works here.

Comment: Are you getting any other errors?  I'm in a place I can actually test it, and I'm getting an error getting $regKey to set properly.  I'll look into it and see what I can find.

Comment: Error says:
Exception calling "GetValueKind" with "1" argument(s): "The specified registry key does not exist."
At D:\Whiz\MyScripts\findPS1.ps1:7 char:28
+ $ref = $regKey.GetValueKind <<<< ("\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellEngine\PowerShellVersion")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

... though this script looks OK, looks like something about the way it calls the registry. I am still trying to figure this out.

Comment: I cannot test anything right now, but when I get back to work Monday, I'll see if I can figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I fixed the script above.  It is working in my environment. Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: worked like a charm! thanks a lot Nick! (I did not get a chance to test this out sooner)

Comment: do you know of a way we can input multiple credentials for servers in multiple domains (Ihave a few servers which use Citrix and are in a different domain. I can just check them physically, though it would be great to know if we can do this)

Comment: For my environment I have a .csv with all the relevant information (domain, username, pass).  I then load it into an array and step through it with a ForEach loop.  All of my domains are test domains, and are isolated, so storing the PW in a .csv isn't an issue.  If security is an issue for you, you can export the secure string into a file, and import that for your PW.

Answer (score 3):

I'd check this key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellEngine\powershellversion.

Comment: This is correct. However, with all due respect, I cannot mark this as the answer for the only reason that my query was to check multiple/list of machines.